# Python Plotly Sankey Diagram: how to calculate 'value' based on 'source' and 'target so all lines are the same height as nodes

Tags: python, plotly, sankey-diagram

So I realise that this is quite a specific question, but it's been bugging me for ages and I can't seem to find a solution..

I am using Plotly with Python to produce Sankey diagrams.  I have the following source, target, and value figures:

```
    source  target  value
0      0.0     5.0    1.0
1      0.0     6.0    1.0
2      1.0     6.0    1.0
3      2.0     7.0    1.0
4      3.0     8.0    1.0
5      4.0     8.0    1.0
6      5.0     9.0    1.0
7      6.0    10.0    1.0
8      7.0     9.0    1.0
9      8.0     9.0    1.0
10     9.0    11.0    1.0
11     9.0    12.0    1.0
12     9.0    13.0    1.0
13    10.0    13.0    1.0
14    10.0    14.0    1.0
15    11.0    15.0    1.0
16    12.0    15.0    1.0
17    12.0    16.0    1.0
18    13.0    16.0    1.0
19    14.0    17.0    1.0
20    15.0    18.0    1.0
21    15.0    19.0    1.0
22    16.0    18.0    1.0
23    17.0    19.0    1.0
```

Which produce the following [unsmoothed Sankey diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHRbW.png)

However, you can see that some of the connecting lines are not the same as the corresponding nodes (e.g. the line flowing out of node i is shorter than node i).

Annoyingly, Plotly doesn't seem to give you the option to automatically smooth the node-line height differences.  You can do this manually with simple diagrams, but it's virtually impossible with complex ones like the one I've attached - altering the heights in one section mean you have to alter the heights elsewhere, etc. because everything is so interconnected

Do you know how I can calculate 'value' figures based on the 'source' and 'target' lists, such that you get perfect smoothing across all nodes and lines?  (e.g. like this one [smoothed Sankey diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LK7Ac.png))

I feel there must an algorithm that will give a perfect solution no matter what the source and target lists look like, but I can't figure it out..

EDIT:

the code to create the image is:

```
link = dict(source = source, target = target, value = value_ones)
node = dict(label = label, pad=50, thickness=5)
data = go.Sankey(link = link, node=node)
fig = go.Figure(data)
fig.show()
```

label is just a dictionary of unique source values and ascending numbers 0-19

Comment: Your data does not have a label. And where is the original code that created the image?

Comment: @r-beginners - added above