# D3 Sankey diagram - calculate link value based on the number of links

Tags: javascript, recursion, d3.js

What would be the best way to automatically calculate the value of a Sankey diagram link based on the number of links?

For example, the values of the links of the graph bellow has been intentionally set to 1 resulting in:

```js
let graph = {
  "nodes":[
    {"node":0,"name":"node0"},
    {"node":1,"name":"node1"},
    {"node":2,"name":"node2"},
    {"node":3,"name":"node3"},
    {"node":4,"name":"node4"}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":2,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":3,"value":1},
    {"source":0,"target":1,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":4,"value":1},
  ]
};

let margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

let sankey = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(36)
    .nodePadding(290)
    .size([width, height]);

sankey
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .layout(1);

let link = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", sankey.link() )
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
      .sort((a, b) => b.dy - a.dy);

let node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

node
    .append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
    .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
    .style("fill", d => d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")))
    .style("stroke", d => d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2));

node
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", -6)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("transform", null)
  .text(d => d.name)
  .filter(d => d.x < width / 2)
  .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
  .attr("text-anchor", "start");
```

```css
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
}
.link:hover {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery@master/LIB/sankey.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="graph"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to automatically calculate the link value resulting in:

```js
let graph = {
  "nodes":[
    {"node":0,"name":"node0"},
    {"node":1,"name":"node1"},
    {"node":2,"name":"node2"},
    {"node":3,"name":"node3"},
    {"node":4,"name":"node4"}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":2,"value":2},
    {"source":2,"target":3,"value":1},
    {"source":0,"target":1,"value":2},
    {"source":2,"target":4,"value":1},
  ]
};

let margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 450 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

let sankey = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(36)
    .nodePadding(290)
    .size([width, height]);

sankey
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .layout(1);

let link = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", sankey.link() )
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
      .sort((a, b) => b.dy - a.dy);

let node = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

node
    .append("rect")
    .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
    .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
    .style("fill", d => d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")))
    .style("stroke", d => d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2));

node
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", -6)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("transform", null)
  .text(d => d.name)
  .filter(d => d.x < width / 2)
  .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
  .attr("text-anchor", "start");
```

```css
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
}
.link:hover {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Load the sankey.js function -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery@master/LIB/sankey.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="graph"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The link between node0 and node1, and between node1 and node2 has been manually set to 2, but I would like this value to be calculated.

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zoranbacev/fsrukax3/9/).

Any help is welcome!

Update: a similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65380593/python-plotly-sankey-diagram-how-to-calculate-value-based-on-source-and-ta). It is about calculating link value based on the number of links between nodes of a Sankey diagram made with Python and Plotly. Personally, I consider that this is more of an algorithmic question than a D3 (or Plotly) question.

Comment: Calculated how?  Is it a "2" because `0 -> 1 -> 2` is continuous?  And `2 -> 4` / `3 -> 4` is a "1" because it is not continuous?

Comment: The value of the link between node0 and node1 should be 2 because node2 is the source of 2 links and node1 is the source of node2, and node0 is the source of node1 